# Image doesn't appear in my "media" folder after upload Django

Tags: python, django, image, upload

I have some trouble uploading picture with Django.

**settings.py**:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

**models.py**:

```
class Dater(AbstractUser):
   AbstractUser.username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   AbstractUser.password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="users_picture", blank=True, null=True)
   summary = models.TextField()
   ....
```

**forms.py**:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your username'}))
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type': 'password','placeholder': 'Enter your password'}))
   summary = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-xs-2'}))
...

class Meta:
    model = models.Dater
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'summary',
              'picture']
```

**My html**:

```
<form id="signupForm" method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% include 'website/form-template.html' %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**:

```
class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'website/signup.html'

    # Display the form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # Process the form
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            # Cleaning and normalizing data
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.latitude = 24.8047 # api call later
            user.longitude = 120.9714 # api call later
            user.save()
```

I have create a folder: "uploads" at the same level than the file `manage.py`. Inside this folder I also create another folder: "users_picture" where I was expected my picture to be uploads to, but when I add the user the image is not upload at all.

Comment: Your models.py is *very* weird. Why are you setting those two fields on AbstractUser? Anyway, to solve this problem we need to see your view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did that because the class already have username and password fields so apparently I can't overwritten it